# Unresolved reference CaptureAcivity in Android Studio Using ZXing

Tags: zxing, barcode-scanner

I am creating a barcode scanner app in Android Studio, unfortunately am encountering error when i run the app. the following is the line of code returning an error saying unresolved reference

I run the code below still i was getting error saying unresolved reference for ActivityCapture

<activity

```
           android:name=".MainActivity"

            android:exported="true"

            android:label="@string/app_name"

            android:theme="@style/Theme.KotlinQRCodeScanner">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureAcitivity"

            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"

            tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"/>
```